# Selenium C# Not able to redirect after the click for login

Tags: c#, selenium

I met problems of not able to log in with selenium. I think the login button is clicked successfully. But the website that I am testing against has some login-check or rest-assured Ajax handling which I don't know. So after I click the login button on the website, I am not able to log in and redirect. I am not sure what's going on.

The website I am practising is https://www.catch.com.au/.

```
  
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System;

namespace Selenium429ErrorDemo
{
    public class Tests
    {

        string url = "https://www.catch.com.au/";
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-testid='myaccount-reference']")).Click();
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_email")).SendKeys("EMAIL");
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_password")).SendKeys("PASSWORD");
           
            IWebElement btn = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("button-login"));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(btn));
            btn.Click();

            IWebElement ert = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".css-n11h0l"));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlMatches("https://www.catch.com.au/"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I visited the login page and i don't think there are any ajax calls happening. You can verify that from the network tab, in dev tools. Not sure tho what issue it's causing with Selenium, but the common issue that i can think of is the way you're selecting the button. Instead of using the css class to select it(which i believe is dynamic and might change overtime), select it via it's `XPath`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am thinking maybe it is because some websites block automation behaviour so that's why I can't redirect to the certain page